# PHP multiplication weird behavior

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, multiplication

I don't know if I have suffered some brain or sight damage, but I can't understand behavior of this code:

```
$po=1;
$po2=0;
echo $po.'*'.$po2.'=';
if($po*$po2) $po=1;
echo $po;
```

I'd expect the output to be 1*0=0, but actually it's 1*0=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$po`  is always 1.  You initialize it to 1, and later in your `if` case, you have no `else`. So it remains `1`.

Instead, add an `else:

```
$po = 1;
$po2 = 0;
echo $po.'*'.$po2.'=';
if ($po * $po2) {

  // Unnecessary - it's already 1
  $po = 1;
}
// Set it to 0...
else {
  $po = 0;
}
echo $po;
```